# SSH and scp work with Google Compute Engine VM, but SFTP doesn't work

Tags: sftp, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've read the other questions on setting up SFTP (using Transmit on OS X) into a Google Compute Engine VM. My issue is that I can currently SSH and use scp into the VM, but Transmit throws a bad login or password error. How to I troubleshoot and fix this?

I've added my SSH key to each VM and to the metadata for the GC account, and I can SSH from my local machine using, i.e. ssh -i my_key user@12.345.678.10 as well as use scp from localhost.

But why doesn't SFTP work? Transmit client loads SSH keys automatically for other hosts.

I've cleared entries in my known_hosts and tried again, with no luck.

Port 22 is obviously open on the VM.

Password auth is not allowed in the host machine's ssh config; does it need to be?

I'm am not using Google Cloud SDK, since SSH and scp already work.

Debug:

```
ssh -v -i my_key user@12.345.678.10

OpenSSH_8.1p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /usr/local/etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 12.345.678.10 [12.345.678.10] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file my_key type 0
debug1: identity file my_key-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u8 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 35.202.168.10:22 as 'user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: [key]
debug1: Host '12.345.678.10' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts:66
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: my_key RSA SHA256:[key] explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: my_key RSA SHA256:[key] explicit
debug1: Server accepts key: my_key RSA SHA256:[key] explicit
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 12.345.678.10 ([12.345.678.10]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network

sftp -v -i my_key user@12.345.678.10

OpenSSH_8.1p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /usr/local/etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 12.345.678.10 [12.345.678.10] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file my_key type 0
debug1: identity file my_key-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u8 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 35.202.168.10:22 as 'user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: [key]
debug1: Host '12.345.678.10' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts:66
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: my_key RSA SHA256:[key] explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: my_key RSA SHA256:[key] explicit
debug1: Server accepts key: my_key RSA SHA256:[key] explicit
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 12.345.678.10 ([12.345.678.10]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
Connected to 12.345.678.10.
sftp>

ssh_config on 12.345.678.10

Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
#   RhostsRSAAuthentication no
#   RSAAuthentication yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   Port 22
#   Protocol 2,1
#   Cipher 3des
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

Comment: Could you run `sftp` with the "-v" option to print debugging output, then [edit] your question to include the output? Also include the actual sftp command that you ran and any entries from your .ssh/config file that might be relevant. It would also be helpful to see the same information for a successful ssh session.

Comment: Thanks, I'll run those debugs and add the results.

Comment: Include also an output of `ssh -v  -i my_key myaccount@123.45.653.99` for comparison.

Comment: That''s interesting; SFTP works from the command line but not in my FTP client. But my FTP client works with SFTP on other machines at other hosts.

Comment: So show us the logs!

Comment: Thanks, not enough coffee this morning :) The Transmit logs were the key; they showed that the SSH key wasn't be read due to its name or format.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that Transmit was looking for keys in the local ~/.ssh, but the error in the Transmit logs was that the key wasn't found due to the key's name or format; the fix was to specifically add the key at the bottom of the local `ssh_config` and restart SSH:

`in /ssh/ssh_config`:

```
Host 12.345.678.10
User user
IdentityFile "~/.ssh/my_key"
```